# How to allow mutilple page to insert multiple data at the same time (will not clash) in MySQL PHP

Tags: php

I have a online page which will allow user to create an account for them in order to acceess our page.

I worry in some period, there will be a lots of user who create at the same time.
In that case, I worry my database will be clash or  conflict.

Can I know is that anyway to prevent that happens?

My table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`userid` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`password` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL
) 

ALTER TABLE `user`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ADD UNIQUE KEY `userid` (`participant_id`);

ALTER TABLE `user`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
COMMIT;
```

So my `id` will be just number and auto increment.
`userid` wil be unique.

I created the page by using PHP.
And I use following insert command at my page:

```
do {
       $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO user(userid, password, name) VALUES ('$userid','$password','$name')";
       $insert = $conn->query($query);

    } while( $insert && ($conn -> affected_rows == 0) );
```

Are this code can work perfectly to prevent the date conflit?

Another extra question is, how about if I create another extra page which will insert information 'user' table and can I used the same code at the new page?

Comment: You'll be fine for avoiding conflicts, though your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please look into prepared statements.